# Bash script calling make and exit status code

Tags: bash, makefile

I Have a very simple Makefile:

```
code_quality:
    flake8 --max-line-length 99 foo_bar
```

And a bash script for my continuous integration tool (run_tests.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

[stuff]

make code_quality

[stuff]
```

When make code_quality fails the exit status code is 2 and is not interpreted as an error by Team City. When there are no errors it returns 0.

How can I make it to be 1?

Comment: `((! $?))` run after a command will convert all non zero exit codes to 1

Comment: Why does Team City not interpret any non-zero exit status as failure?  Which foreign environment does it come from?  On Unix, any non-zero exit status indicates failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but if you want the bash script to exit with status 1 when make fails, try:

```
make code_quality || exit 1
```